# Magento 2 Add Customer Attribute Database

Tags: magento2, customer

I've written a module to add a customer attribute. I then realised I needed another one. I thought it would be easier to add this via database.

I've added the required values to:

```
eav_attribute
customer_eav_attribute
customer_eav_attribute_website
```

And the attribute shows up lovely, but whenever I go to save it nothing happens.

I appreciate in hindsight this probably wasn't the smartest way to go about it, but what am I missing?

Comment: Tried to reindex database?

Answer (score 2):

May be this would be help you :

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "bank_account_number",  array(
        "type"     => "static",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Bank Account Number",
        "input"    => "text",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => false,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""

    ));

    $bankaccountnumber   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "bank_account_number");

    $bankaccountnumber = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'bank_account_number');
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
    $bankaccountnumber->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100);
    $bankaccountnumber->save();
```

This will add your attribute to all table that an attribute need to be stored.